# What does %[] mean in PHP?

Tags: php

I've got a .css file in a legacy application that has PHP statements in it to change it dynamically. At the top I have something like this:

```
<?
$GLOBALS["global_vars"] = array(
    "form_width" => "%[form_width]"
);
?>
```

Then later in the file, I see this (it is not inside a php block).

```
table {
  width: %[form_width];
}
```

This has left me with a couple of questions I can't figure out.

1. What does the %[] syntax mean exactly? Is that some kind of directive to PHP to do a substitution? Or is it literally the name of the variable, since it was in quotes earlier?
2. I want to change the value of %[form_width] later in the file. Can I do that outside a PHP block? Regardless of where I do it, how do I assign to it? I'm used to variables have a $ in front, but in this case, do I just do something like this:

   ```
   %[form_width] = 200px;
   ```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Is it possible that this is a template system, and that the template engine will parse that for you?

Comment: This is part of a string literal and doesn't have any meaning in PHP itself.

Comment: unless `form_width` is somehow set to a constant, I dont see anything other than a string with its application.

Comment: Nothing. `%[]` means nothing to PHP.

Comment: @TecBrat @Ice76
It may be a templating system, I'm not sure. But the actual value (which is a constant) was set in a PHP block in another file. Here it is:


`<?
$GLOBALS["global_vars"] = array(
    "form_width" => 270px
);
?>`

That's why I assumed it was PHP doing this and not just a templating system. Also, I am sure people will wonder why I don't just change the above statement. That would globally affect the application, and I just want to change `%[form_width]` for a specific file.

Comment: @TecBrat Thanks for pointing me toward the idea of a template system. And thanks to Ice76, Sammitch and Felix Kling for confirming it wasn't a valid PHP directive. Once I realized it wasn't PHP and that it could be a templating system, I looked around for one, and there is one that I didn't know about! So this one is solved. Thanks so much for all your help everyone. TecBrat, if you want to change your comment to an answer, I'll mark it correct and you can get the points.

Answer (score 0):

That appears to be part of a template system. I don't recognize it, so I can't tell you which one it is. The template engine will likely parse that for you.